# The box '....' could not be found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14. I have vagrant and virtual-box installed. And I have a file from a Vagrantfiile from a repository. However, I always get this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The box 'hoatle/iorad' could not be found.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Linux 14 since there are a lot of different Linux distributions. Do you know which distro you're using? Also, could you edit your post to include your Vagrantfile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. It might be a better fit for https://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: @PatrickLee: The question is tagged "ubuntu", so presumably it's Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 (most likely the former since that's the long term support release).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so vagrant cannot find your box in atlas, weird because it seems its there : https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hoatle/boxes/iorad

you can try to install the box directly with `vagrant box add hoatle/iorad` but I guess it will not work in your case neither.

try to download the box file directly from `wget https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hoatle/boxes/iorad/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box` and then install the box in vagrant with `vagrant box add hoatle/iorad <path to your downloaded box file>`